# Open new activity after passing argument

Tags: android, android-activity, authentication, arguments

Can someone help me? How do I open a new activity after passing basic login argument, here's my code and I don't know what's going, I get an error:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText usern = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.user_name);
    String user_name = usern.getText().toString();
    EditText passw = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    String pass_word = passw.getText().toString();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void nextPage(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button
        if (user_name.equals("sheldonmad") && pass_word.equals("password")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post your error please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@Sheldon Madison** : Try this way . Need proper **Initialization** of Global or local variables .
Please read Official Documents 
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/index.html

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
        public void nextPage(View view) {

        EditText usern = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        String user_name = usern.getText().toString();
        EditText passw = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        String pass_word = passw.getText().toString();
            // Do something in response to button
            if (user_name.equals("sheldonmad") && pass_word.equals("password")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     EditText usern,passw;
     String user_name,pass_word;

                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                usern = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.user_name);                    
                passw = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);                  
                }

                /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
                public void nextPage(View view) {

    user_name = usern.getText().toString();
  pass_word = passw.getText().toString();
                    // Do something in response to button
                    if (user_name.equals("sheldonmad") && pass_word.equals("password")) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            }
```